# Re-initate third-party script after language change in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a live chat support button on a `Next.js 13` app that it's added as follows in the component that renders the button:

```
import Script from 'next/script';
...
<div id={`onlinehelp-button-${codePlan}`}>
<Script
    id="chatjs"
    strategy="afterInteractive"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
            var OnlineHelpAPI=OnlineHelpAPI||{};(function(t){function e(e){var a=document.createElement("script"),c=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=e+t.site_id,c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c)}t.chat_buttons=t.chat_buttons||[],t.chat_buttons.push({code_plan:"${codePlan}",div_id:"onlinehelp-button-${codePlan}"}),t.site_id=60003785,t.main_code_plan="${codePlan}",e("https://vue.livehelp100service.com/livechat.ashx?siteId="),setTimeout(function(){t.loaded||e("https://vue.livehelp100servicestandby.com/livechat.ashx?siteId=")},5e3)})(OnlineHelpAPI||{})
        `,
    }}
/>
</div>
```

When the language changes, the `codePlan` changes and then a different live support chat should be available in a different language. This works if I reload the page after changing the language, but it's a much better UX if there is no page reload because it's not necessary for the language change.

I can't figure out how to re-add/re-initiate the script on language change. When the `codePlan` changes I'm just left with the empty `` <div id={`onlinehelp-button-${codePlan}`}> `` but no script is added to the page's `HTML` and therefore not Live Chat button. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

We'll probably need some back and forth as I don't have the exact `codePlan` to be able to properly instantiate the bundle script that gets added (I get a
TypeError of some sort).

In any case, how about something along these lines where you remove the script physically when codePlan changes and then the IIFE begins its procedure again with the updated `codePlan`?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!codePlan) return;
    const liveHelpScript = document.querySelector("#LiveHelpScript");
    if (liveHelpScript) {
      liveHelpScript.remove();
    }
    (function (t) {
      function e(e) {
        var a = document.createElement("script"),
          c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        (a.type = "text/javascript"),
          (a.id = "LiveHelpScript"),
          (a.async = !0),
          (a.src = e + t.site_id),
          c.parentNode.insertBefore(a, c);
      }
      (t.chat_buttons = t.chat_buttons || []),
        t.chat_buttons.push({
          code_plan: `${codePlan}`,
          div_id: `onlinehelp-button-${codePlan}`,
        }),
        (t.site_id = 60003785),
        (t.main_code_plan = `${codePlan}`),
        e("https://vue.livehelp100service.com/livechat.ashx?siteId="),
        setTimeout(function () {
          t.loaded ||
            e(
              "https://vue.livehelp100servicestandby.com/livechat.ashx?siteId=",
            );
        }, 5e3);
    })(OnlineHelpAPI || {});
  }, [codePlan]);
```

and put this one somewhere outside the component:

```
var OnlineHelpAPI = OnlineHelpAPI || {};
```

Since I can't really see what happens with the minified bundle assets from the Livechat website you're referring to, you might have to remove the buttons (if any) that got added somewhere after the first `.remove()`, e.g.:

```
const removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='onlinehelp-button-']")
if (removeButtons) {
    removeButtons.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought this would work but I haven't managed to. The `OnlineHelpApi` object gets created and the `IIFE` runs and I can see the `t` variable with the correct `chat_buttons` but then those buttons aren't in the `OnlineHelpApi` object. I've managed to have a solution where I'm rendering both support buttons and hiding them with `CSS` depending on the plan. So this will do for now.